# Can "plus" be order preserving as "times": does there exist a function $h$ such that $x\times y=x' \times y'\iff x+h(y)=x'+h(y')$?

Tags: real-analysis

Background: $x\mapsto e^x$ is an order preserving transformation as $2<3$ means $e^2<e^3$. However, the multiplication operation is not order preserving as addition. For example, $1+6>3+3$ but $1\times 6<3\times 3$.

**Question**: Given $x,y,x',y'$ positive real numbers, does there exist a continuous real function $h$ such that $x\times y>x' \times y'\iff x+h(y)>x'+h(y')$?

**Motivation** Can addition be (ordinally) the same as multiplication? The above equation means that the multiplication operation between two number $x$ and $y$ has the same ordinal order as the addition operation!

My guess is "no".

Comment: @AnneBauval This is just a thought experiment to get an idea of the property

Comment: I didn't follow how you got $h(\epsilon)\geq 1+h(0)$ after $f(\epsilon)+h(\epsilon)>f(0)+h(0)$, or why this implies a discontinuity for $h$

Comment: @TonyMathew Clarified!

Comment: You can't choose $f$ continuous with $f(0)=1$ and $f(\epsilon)=\epsilon$ for $\epsilon$ arbitrarily small.

Comment: @jjagmath You are right, I'll double think

Comment: What do you mean by the "ordinal order" of multiplication and addition? Does the fact that $x \mapsto e^x$ is an order-preserving bijection between $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R_{>0}$ which maps addition to multiplication perhaps also imply whatever you mean by this?

Comment: @PaulSinclair Addition operation involves two numbers. considering $x+y$ and $x^y$, it is not order preserving: $1+6>3+3$ but $1^6<3+3$

Comment: My question is that although $x+y$ and $x\times y$ is not order preserving, can there be a transformation be order preserving. I'll edit the question to clarify

Comment: You are still talking about the "ordinal number" of multiplication and of addition on the *real numbers*, which does not make any sense. Ordinal numbers are types of *well-orderings*, and the real numbers are not well-ordered. And even if you restrict to natural numbers, which are well-ordered, what you mean by the "ordinal number" of a binary operation is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us prove by contradiction that such a function $h$ doesn't exist. Assume it does. Then, for every $x,y,x',y'>0,$
$$x>x'\frac{y'}y\iff x>x'+h(y')-h(y),$$
which implies for every $y,x',y'>0,$
$$x'\frac{y'}y=x'+h(y')-h(y),$$
i.e.
$$x'\left(\frac{y'}y-1\right)=h(y')-h(y).$$
But this entails
$\forall y,y'>0\quad \frac{y'}y-1=0,$ which is clearly false.

Comment: A couple clarifications for the slower-witted such as myself, who had to think about it a bit to figure out why: The first implication follows because the equivalence holds for all $x$, which means as you vary $x$, the LH and RH inequalities switch from being true to false at the same time. The entailment follows because if $\frac{y'}y - 1 \ne 0$, the equation can be solved for $x'$ as a function of the other variables, but it is supposed to hold for all $x'$.

Comment: If you like. But my way of thinking was rather: the first implication stems from the fact that when two sets (of $x$'s) are equal, their lubs are equal. And the entailment can be proved directly: if $\forall x'>0\quad x'a=b,$ then $2a=b=a$ hence $a=0.$

Comment: Perfect answer!